# Android URL Encoding

Tags: java, android, url

I am using the following code to read the webpage contents:

```
 String website="";
    try {
        website = URLEncoder.encode(arg0[0],"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      Document doc;
    try {
           doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
           Elements el=doc.getElementsByClass("header");
           Elements atr= doc.select("p span");
           for(Element s:atr)
           ss+="\n"+s.text();
           text=el.text();
        TextView   t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.titlenews1);
        TextView  t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.body);
           t1.setText(text);
           t2.setText(ss);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
```

If I place the URL directly in the `website="http://www.mcpss.com/?PN='News2'&SubP='DNewsStory'&gn=&NewsID=47318&ShowNav=&StoryGroup=Current"`  I am getting the document.

If I pass the URL from parsing the XML file I am not able to get the document (I am getting exception)

How can I do this, there is any URL encoding technique to get the document?

Comment: Post the exception stack trace

Comment: i am getting the problem near doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();

Comment: Fine, but you still didn't **post the stack trace**.

Comment: where should i check the stack trace

Comment: Should be in the console. If you're using Eclipse, it's in the LogCat view.

Comment: i am using eclipse i am not getting any thing in my console

Comment: *If you're using Eclipse*, **it's in the LogCat view**

Comment: 01-22 18:45:20.543: DEBUG/SntpClient(43): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: Log the content of `arg0[0]` to logcat, and put it into the question. `URLEncoder.encode` is for encoding the query parameters of the URL, not the whole URL.

Comment: i am getting the correct link when log the arg0[0]. this is the link where i am parsing the Link tag-http://www.mobileapp.pcmac.org/mobile/xml/sisapp.asp?sid=353&pn=news2

Comment: i am getting Http error fetching url moskit0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url);
```

to decode

```
String decodedUrl = URLDecoder.decode(encodedUrl)
```